# Accessing list elements when counting the number of rectilinear paths

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, haskell, combinatorics

I am trying to solve the [RIVALS problem on SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/RIVALS/): Starting from (0, 0), how many paths are there to reach point (X, Y), only taking one-unit steps moving to the right or up?  *Constraints: 0 ≤ X ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>, 0 ≤ Y ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>, answer is to be given modulo (10<sup>9</sup> + 7).*

I am facing a performance issue with accessing elements of a list. I am also facing a runtime error if I am trying to access the list element.

In order to get the n<sup>th</sup> element I am using `[1,1,1,2]!!n`, but I have been told that this runs in O(n) which is very slow.  Is there any other data structure in Haskell which gives O(1) access time for n<sup>th</sup> element?

About my algorithm: the number of way to move form (0,0) to (x,y) in 2D plain and answer is:

$$\frac{(x+y)!}{x!\ y!}$$

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}
import Data.List
import Data.Bits
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

seqI :: Integer -> Integer
seqI x = seq x x

seqB :: Bool -> Bool
seqB x = seq x x



modExp' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modExp' r b p m = let nextR = seqI $ (seqI $ r*b)`rem` m
                      nextB = seqI $ (seqI $ b*b)`rem` m
                      nextP = seqI $ shiftR  p 1
                      incl  = seqB $ testBit p 0
                      cont  = seqB $ nextP  /= 0
                  in  if incl
                         then if cont
                                 then modExp' nextR nextB nextP m
                                 else nextR
                         else if cont
                                 then modExp' r     nextB nextP m
                                 else r

modExp :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
modExp b p m = modExp' 1 b p m

readInts :: IO [Int]
readInts = fmap (map read.words) getLine

read2Ints :: IO [Int]
read2Ints = do
     ints <- readInts
     if length ints == 2 then return ints else do
         putStrLn ("sorry, could you give me exactly two integers, "
                  ++ "separated by spaces?")
         read2Ints

p = 1000000007::Integer
ip = 1000000005::Integer
mtimes a b =  (a * b)`rem`p
facts = scanl mtimes 1 [1..2000001]

anstable ::[Integer]
anstable  =  facts

solve ::Int->Int-> Integer
solve x y = anstable!!(x+y)*(modExp (anstable!!x) ip p)*(modExp (anstable!!y) ip p)`rem`1000000007


main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    forM_ [1..n::Int] (\i -> do
       xs <- read2Ints
       print $(solve (head xs) (last xs)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Code organization

The definitions of `readInts` and `read2Ints` disrupt the mathematical code.  The I/O routines belong further down, just before `main`.

`import Data.Maybe` and `import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C` appear to be superfluous.

### Abstraction

It is not immediately obvious from reading

> ```
> solve x y = anstable!!(x+y)*(modExp (anstable!!x) ip p)*(modExp (anstable!!y) ip p)`rem`1000000007
> ```

that it is calculating

$$ \left(\begin{array}{c} x+y \\ y \end{array}\right) = \frac{(x + y)!}{x!\ y!}\mod p $$

I would expect to see

```
solve x y = modCombination (x + y) y p

modCombination n r p =
  (factorial n) * (modInvFactorial r) * (modFactorial (n - r)) `rem` p'
  where …
```

In some ways, you come close, but `anstable` obscures your intention.  Why not `ansTable`, with the customary capitalization so that it doesn't look like `an stable`? Why did you rename it from `fact` in the first place, making it more confusing?  Why is `1000000007` hard-coded at the end, when you could have used `p`?

What is `ip`?  `1000000005` is a magic number that appears nowhere in the stated challenge.  What about `2000001`?  Where did that limit come from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am very new to Haskell so please forgive me for poor coding style. I have already solved this problem on spoj.I am learning Haskell and trying to code some easy problems in Haskell.P is mod and ip I am using while finding mod inverse of factorial x using Fermat theorem. Now come to the limit max value of x & y in this problem can be 10^6 and on finding nCr we need factorial (x+y) that's why factorial limit is 200001. About import libraries Initially I was using different method to read the data because of some issue I changed the   input reading method.